# ASP.NET 2.0 page gets HTTP Error 403 under System7 IIS 7.5 but works fine under Server 2008 Std IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Here is my code:

```
    protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // some variables
            const string number_of_parameters = "5";
            const string name_of_parameters = "AccountID|ReturnAddress|StatementDate|SubTotalByAccount|SubTotalByDept|";
            const string outf = "-Epdf";
            string value_of_parameters;
            string output_file_name;
            string vAttachment;
            byte[] myFile;
            string ExportDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Reports\\OutPut\\" +
                AppLib.GetSessionValue("UserID").Trim() + "\\";

            // Email Statements if it is set in Defaults
            bool isEmailed = false;
            LLdataSet.S_Invoice_EmailRow emailRow = null;
            if (defaultsRow.DefEmailStatements)
            {
                emailRow = emailLogic.GetEmailSetupByID(2);
                if (trEmail.Visible == true && rblEmail.SelectedValue == "1")
                    isEmailed = true;
            }

            // Archive Statements if S_CUSTOMER_INTEGRATION supports it and it is set in Defaults
            bool isArchived = false;
            DateTime deleteDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900");
            if (BaseControl.CheckCustomerIntegrationSetings("UseAdvancedDocLib") == "1")
            {
                if (defaultsRow.DefArchiveMonths > 0)
                {
                    deleteDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(defaultsRow.DefArchiveMonths);
                    if (trAchive.Visible == true && rblArchive.SelectedValue == "1")
                        isArchived = true;
                }
            }

            //Make sure ARTempReport is empty
            reportLogic.CoastClear();

            //Run a detailed ARTB
            SqlParameter[] myParamList = new SqlParameter[11];
            myParamList[0] = new SqlParameter("@location", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            myParamList[0].Value = ddlLocation.SelectedValue;
            myParamList[1] = new SqlParameter("@route", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            myParamList[1].Value = "%";
            myParamList[2] = new SqlParameter("@salesPerson", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4);
            myParamList[2].Value = "%";
            myParamList[3] = new SqlParameter("@chain", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            myParamList[3].Value = "%";
            myParamList[4] = new SqlParameter("@customerGroup", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            myParamList[4].Value = "%";
            myParamList[5] = new SqlParameter("@aquireGroup", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5);
            myParamList[5].Value = "%";
            myParamList[6] = new SqlParameter("@agingStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            myParamList[6].Value = "0";
            myParamList[7] = new SqlParameter("@reportType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            myParamList[7].Value = "1";
            myParamList[8] = new SqlParameter("@asOfDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
            myParamList[8].Value = txtDate.Text;
            myParamList[9] = new SqlParameter("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
            myParamList[9].Value = AppLib.GetSessionValue("UserID");
            myParamList[10] = new SqlParameter("@checkUseStatements", SqlDbType.Bit, 1);
            myParamList[10].Value = true;
            string vConnStr = AppLib.GetSessionValue("ConnectionString");
            DBLib.RunStoredProc("dbo.FaR_TrialBalance", vConnStr, myParamList);


            //Iterate througe list of unique accounts
            List<int> accountList = reportLogic.GetDistinctAccounts();
            foreach (int vAccountID in accountList)
            {
                customerRow = customerLogic.GetByID(vAccountID);
                value_of_parameters = vAccountID.ToString() + "|" + rblReturnAddress.SelectedValue + "|" +
                    txtDate.Text + "|" + customerRow.UseSubtotalByAccount.ToString() + "|" +
                    customerRow.UseSubtotalByDepartment.ToString() + "|";
                output_file_name = "ARST_" + txtDate.Text.Replace("/", "") + "_" + vAccountID.ToString();
                string[] arg = { outf, "-XFile", "-O" + output_file_name, "-N" + number_of_parameters, "-A" + name_of_parameters, "-J" + value_of_parameters };
                RptInfo rf = new RptInfo(arg);
                rf.DatabaseName = DataBase.ToString().Trim();
                //Create the pdf
                vAttachment = rf.CrExport("ARReports\\Statements.rpt");

                if (isEmailed && trEmail.Visible)
                {
                    // email to all contacts
                    List<string> emailList = deptLogic.GetAPContacts(vAccountID);
                    if (emailList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        FuncLib.SendEmail(emailRow.Host, emailRow.FromEmail, string.Join(";", emailList.ToArray()), "",
                            emailRow.Subject, emailRow.Body, Server.MapPath(vAttachment), (int?)emailRow.Port, (int?)emailRow.Priority,
                            (bool?)emailRow.EnableSs1, emailRow.Username, emailRow.Password);
                    }
                }

                if (isArchived && trAchive.Visible)
                {
                    //store the pdf in the customer's documents repository
                    myFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(vAttachment));
                    documentLogic.AddDocument(customerRow.Location, customerRow.Account, output_file_name + ".pdf", "Statement As Of " + txtDate.Text,
                        1, myFile, deleteDate);
                }
                //string message1 = "<FONT color=\"blue\"><STRONG> Account#" + vAccountID.ToString() + "</STRONG></FONT>: Statement Created <br>";
                //Response.Write(message1);
                //Response.Flush();
            }
```

My problem is that once I click the button that fires this code off (and that is with both the emailing and archiving functions being skipped), after somewhere between 7 and 20 seconds later, I get the "This page can't be displayed" screen.  Clicking the "Fix connection problems" button, I'm told the underlying reason is 403 - permissions.

I don't believe it.  In the first place, if I either reduce the amount of data I'm looking at, or uncomment out the above Response.Write/.Flush commands, the page works.  Secondly, the page works as is on our server.

I have spent 2 days researching why this is happening and I am going nowhere.  Please help!

Comment: How much data are we talking about? You might be hitting some user-specific data-throttling threshold in the newer version of IIS. And am I seeing that correctly? .NET 2.0???

Comment: Yes, v2.0.  I inherited this site and am very new to ASP.NET so I have been taking small steps.  The thing is, all of the code get's executed.  All the PDF's get created, combined, deleted, just as called for but when I go to display the final PDF, I get the error.